# I am getting an extra empty {} json object along with a && before my output from a simple spring mvc json service

Tags: java, json, spring, model-view-controller, jackson

OK, I have a spring mvc based json web service. This is a test app, I have never seen a problem like this when building spring mvc based restful json services. The output of my test service always returns and empty json object followed by && followed by the data i want to return. So the result looks like this:

{} && {"status":200,"serverTime":"January 6, 2013 7:35:45 PM EST"}

The code for my controller method to process this very simple GET request is:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test.json", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelMap test(ModelMap m, HttpServletRequest request,
        Locale locale) {
    Date date = new Date();
    DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG,
            DateFormat.LONG, locale);

    String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

    m.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate);
    m.addAttribute("status", 200);

    return m;
}
```

I cant for the life of me figure out where that extra empty {} json object is coming from. my spring config looks like this:

```
<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="mediaTypes">
        <beans:map>
            <beans:entry key="html" value="text/html" />
            <beans:entry key="json" value="application/json" />
        </beans:map>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="defaultViews">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:bean
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView">
                <beans:property name="prefixJson" value="true" />
            </beans:bean>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="viewResolvers">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
                <beans:property name="viewClass"
                    value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
                <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
                <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
            </beans:bean>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have blown through 6 hours on a sunday trying to figure out why this is happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the `MappingJacksonJsonView` javadoc :

```
public void setPrefixJson(boolean prefixJson)
```

> Indicates whether the JSON output by this view should be prefixed with
>   "{} && ". Default is false. Prefixing the JSON string in this manner
>   is used to help prevent JSON Hijacking. The prefix renders the string
>   syntactically invalid as a script so that it cannot be hijacked. This
>   prefix does not affect the evaluation of JSON, but if JSON validation
>   is performed on the string, the prefix would need to be ignored.

So did you try with prefixJson set to false ?

```
<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="mediaTypes">
        <beans:map>
            <beans:entry key="html" value="text/html" />
            <beans:entry key="json" value="application/json" />
        </beans:map>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="defaultViews">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:bean
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView">
                <beans:property name="prefixJson" value="false" />
            </beans:bean>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="viewResolvers">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
                <beans:property name="viewClass"
                    value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
                <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
                <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
            </beans:bean>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
```

Comment: Jp thank you very much! I can't believe I missed this. That killed a sunday for no reason.

Comment: that fixed it in about 20 seconds! I still can't believe I overlooked that for so many hours. Thanks JP. I guess my sunday had to suck between this and the Redskins loss to the seahawks.

Answer (score 1):

I was receiving the same stuff and I've made the same mistake as you did in the code you provided :) I just accidentally forgot to add annotation `@ResponseBody` to the controller method.